# Enabling CORS in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, cors, asp.net-core-7.0

I can't seem to enable CORS in my ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web app.

Given it didn't work, I've tried to make the simplest possible example that should have it working, based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and several questions on this site.

It still doesn't appear to work. I'm now slight doubting my testing methodology: I'm calling it with postman and hoping to see a `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`  header.

My `program.cs` looks like this: note that I have removed everything not directly needed to just make it run and have CORS enabled:

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

For testing I have used postman:

[image: Headers in postman. Note that there are four of them, none of which is CORS]

I was receiving the following headers:

- Content Type
- Date
- Server
- Transfer-Encoding

As pointed out by the correct answer below, what I wasn't doing was sending origin. Fixing that fixed the problem.
I've run the code on a different machine, on the same network, because I read somewhere that if you test from localhost to localhost the header doesn't always get added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending [an `Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) (I had to squint; please express your request configuration as text not a picture), so the request does not appear to be one that needs permission from CORS. Many CORS handling libraries won't add CORS permission for non-CORS requests.

Comment: That has solved it, thanks! Adding the origin header has made it work.

I'll copy the headers in above as requested to